# nginx port binding issues

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy

Of course the port is already in use! hence my desire to redirect it! - I don't understand how I'm suppose to be able to redirect an app on 8787 to the https version if I can't start nginx due to this bind error?

```
 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
 nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8787 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

server block:

```
server {
    listen 8787;
    listen [::]:8787 ipv6only=on;
        server_name www.example.* example.* 45.224.123.199;

        # SSL
                ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sample.key;
        port_in_redirect off;
        return 302 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: `Of course the port is already in use! hence my desire to redirect it!` What? Who listens on this port?

Comment: A webapp listens on that port but when people go to it I want them to hit the secure https version which is why I want the redirect to https

Comment: Then you need to let the webapp listen on another port. You can't bind to the same port from the webapp and nginx at the same time.

Comment: so I've read but then how do I get a redirect working for the new port for those that go via IP or http ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each application , in this case the upstream application and nginx, need their own unique ip and port binding pair. Generally, ONE application per IP can anybind.

You need to either:

- choose a unique port for the proxy and upstream pairing (change nginx port, or change application port)

OR

- chose a unique IP binding for your application.

Very often, a good practice is to application bind to the LAN ip instead of the public IP, to better isolate your application from the public internet.